# Problem in starting selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting issue in starting selenium. Actually my thread class has selenium.start() in run() method. So when I'm using below lines of code,

```
//some another class
class someclass{

    ScrapeThread nidleThread = new ScrapeThread("nidleThread");    
    Thread scraper = new Thread(niidleThread);
    scraper.start()
}
```

as thread.start() method internally calls run() method, so in run() method of thread class only first two three lines of code are getting executed and when it executes comes to selenium.start() and executes, then selenium is giving issue in starting means I can see only two commands getting executed in command history of selenium remote and then getting struck there.

But when i m using below code and directly calling the run() method of my thread class

```
//some another class
class someclass{
    ScrapeThread nidleThread = new ScrapeThread("nidleThread");    
    nidleThread.run();
}
```

here it's working properly and I'm getting proper output as I want.

What could be the issue in starting selenium when I'm executing the thread in normal way i.e. by calling scrapper.start() method?

```
//in thread class
run(){   
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium(config.getHost(), Integer.parseInt(config.getPort()),          config.getBrowser(), config.getUrl());            
    selenium.start();                                                        
}
```

The code in run() method of thread class

public void run() {

```
    try {

        System.out.println("in the run method");

        scraper = siteToScrape.getSiteScraper();

        scraper.setStartPageType(pageTypeToScrape);

        scraper.setPageTypeToScrape(typeToScrape);

        SocialParser parser = siteToScrape.getSiteParser();
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(config.getHost(), Integer.parseInt(config.getPort()), config.getBrowser(), config.getUrl());
        selenium.start();
        System.out.println("EXECUTED 1!!");//after this nothing is getting                
                                                       //executed
        Integer count = 0;
        System.out.println("EXECUTED 2!!");
        while (startUrl != null) {
        System.out.println("EXECUTED 3!!");
            HtmlPage homePage = new HtmlPage();
            homePage.setCreatedBy(new String());
            homePage.setCreatedon(new String());
            homePage.setModifiedBy(new String());
            homePage.setModifiedOn(new String());
            homePage.setNoOfItemsFound(new String());
            homePage.setOwnedBy(urlOwnedBy);
            homePage.setPageType(scraper.getPageTypeToScrape());
            homePage.setPageUrl(startUrl);
            element  = getInitialisedElement();
            scraper.setNavigator(element.getNavigator());
            scraper.setStartUrl(startUrl);
            try {
                scraper.initialize();//some more stuff
            }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide any error messages the selenium server is giving you?

Comment: Could you please provide Selenium error message, and a part of code, which starts Selenium? Also, please, correct code formatting (select your code and press "{}" button on control panel above text area)

Comment: @jerluc I m not getting any error message  or an exception.In selenium remote's command history box first two commands are getting executed and after that it getting struck there.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your original question. So which commands are you attempting to execute from the RC after the selenium instance is started?

Comment: @jerluc i m trying to open some site.for ex open("http://www.google.com")

Comment: @kel i have modified my question sir.please check.

Comment: I would make sure that the website is opening completely then, maybe using a longer waitForPageLoad() value. 90% of the issues involving Selenium and other browser driver API's involve the inability to detect server latency, browser rendering bottlenecks, etc resulting in your RC trying to move on while the page maybe isn't completely loaded. This is especially true on AJAX-enabled pages.

Comment: @jerluc but selenium's rc's command history box is not showing that the open command is getting executed and in second browser its not doing anything.

Comment: @jerluc below two commands are getting executed                                                                                         getTitle()
setContext(19c9eb07309748e398ffc76a20b8ba4a)                         and after this its getting stuck.

Comment: and when you run it using run() directly, do these same two commands get executed in that order? It just doesn't seem right for getTitle() to be invoked before the context session id is setup first..

Comment: @jerluc yes,the same two commands are getting executed in that order when i m calling the run() method directly and these are the very first two commands which i can see as the selenium gets start.

Comment: yeah I'm not wholly sure then what's going on with it. It does seem to have to do with thread execution discrepancies. Normally you'll want to create an Executor to manage and execute multiple threads. But at the same time it could literally be anything else. Are you able to post a fair amount of your code for us to see?

Comment: @jerluc please check the code in question.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried adding a catch for the top-most try block, to check for any exceptions? And also, in your while () loop, are you sure startUrl is initialized as non-null?

Comment: @jerluc starturl is set to some value and exceptions are handled there.but as i said i m not getting any exceptions or errors.

Comment: @jerluc its not going to that loop coz its getting stuck before that only.even its not going to the very next line i.e.to             Integer count = 0; statement

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm assuming what you're trying to do is create a thread to perform some page-scraping using selenium to drive the browser? If so, I'd make sure that your selenium server config is correct and then also I'd make sure that the selenium.start() isn't being called concurrently with anything trying to invoke any selenium commands.

From my experience, you should be very careful when dealing with multiple threads as if I were to do something like this:

```
Thread threadOne = new Thread(something);
Thread threadTwo = new Thread(somethingElse);
```

threadOne.start();
threadTwo.start();

This does not necessarily mean that threadOne will start before nor exactly concurrently with threadTwo.

Comment: but the thing is that when i m calling run() method directly its working fine with same selenium config.

Comment: That's what I mean, when you call run() directly, you're essentially calling just the method itself, whereas when you are invoking start() your thread is being pooled and will be executed sometime in the near future.